# Issue with a design when content increase

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have design in bootstrap, the amount of content increases the design break.In design both session such as content and name will be equal size(height). That means if content part increase(height) then name part(height) also be increase. 
Please help me to figure out this problem.

```
[demo](http://codepen.io/AbhishekNayar/pen/QELEQR)
```

Comment: Always post relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: i have codepen link attached to the question.

Comment: The key bit there was **in the question itself**. That's *why* SO wouldn't let you post the link raw. Ideally, use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) for an on-site runnable example.

Comment: but when i use use that toolbar i can't shows you the correct design
codepen gives the correct design. http://codepen.io/AbhishekNayar/pen/QELEQR

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.row.pd11 {
    display: flex;
}
```

[link to fix on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWwoJe)